# If statement in math notation using latex

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to find a way to write mathematical notation for an if statement in LaTeX.

For example I would like to have this python code in mathematical notation:

```
def my_function(x):
    result = []
    for ele in x:
        if ele > 0:
            result.append(ele * 2)
        else:
            result.append(0)
    return result
```

I want every element of x to double if the element is above zero, and the the element is not zero, I want it to be set to zero.

`x = [1,3,4, -1,2,-3]`  should become `[2, 6, 8, 0, 4, 0]`.

When Googling around for the answer I came across [Iverson Bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), but this is not quite what I need, though it is close.

My final result should look something like this:

```
result = {if x > 0 => x * 2
         {else x => 0
```

With one big `{`, and prettier looking, but I don't know how to do this in LaTeX.

Comment: `a_n=x_n + \abs{x_n}`

Comment: Using the Iverson bracket, `$2x[x>0]$`, but this is more a math question than (La)TeX

Comment: I am confused. Do you need a macro in LaTeX to evaluate the function on a comma separated array of numbers? If this is just a question about mathematical notation, it's off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I edit my question, I hope it is more clear what I am asking now.

Comment: @Akavall No, it's not clear.

Comment: Thanks @Werner that answers my question perfectly. Sorry that I wasn't able to find it myself.